# i cant get the input to define Y (as yes) to upper i get a traceback call

Tags: input, python-3.6

```
This is for an assignment

when it gets to the Question about pregnant if pregnant = Y if not is N
it throws me back Y is not defined ? because its case-sensitive.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>NameError                                 
>Traceback (most recent call last)
><ipython-input-1-8e4818ff5970> in <module>
>     16 elif Age > 18 and Sex == "F":
>     17     pregnant = input("Are you pregnant (Y)es or (N): ").upper()
>---> 18     if pregnant == Y.upper():
>     19         print("You need a physician's note that you can fly: ")
>  
>
>NameError: name 'Y' is not defined

---------------------------------------------------------------------------


I've tried the following

>pregnant = input("Are you pregnant (Y)es or (N): ")
>pregnant = input.upper("Are you pregnant (Y)es or (N): "))
>pregnant = input("Are you pregnant (Y)es or (N): ").upper()
>pregnant = pregnant.upper()



-------------------------------------
```

The question is to determine whether the traveler is good to go as is or needs extra documentation --- by taking in input to a question of yes or no and return either an OK you are good to go, or need more info  and documents

Comment: `input` will store user input (y, Y, n, N, zqy...), you can convert it to uppercase, but you want to compare it to a string `"Y"`

Comment: Thank you guys for the swift response  - is there a way you can elaborate a litle more about it. how to fix it because the Question (M)ale or (F)emale didn't traceback   and it is constructed the very same way but it accepted the M or F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your line no.18 is that "pregnant" holds either "Y" or "N" in **Character format** . Therefore you need to say **pregnant == 'Y'.upper()**

So, when you're comparing the input in the if condition should look something like this :

```
pregnant = input("Are you pregnant (Y)es or (N)o: ").upper()
if pregnant == 'Y'.upper():
    print("You need a physician's note that you can fly: ")
```

I've tested it and it works fine:

```
Are you pregnant (Y)es or (N): Y
You need a physician's note that you can fly:
```